# Able to get id but unable to do post request

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am able to router get the id but when I reach the retireagent html page and try to press the submit button to confirm the change of agent status, it says id is not defined. I want to change the status of agent by clicking the submit button. Is it due to the way I did the form?

[image: Agent Status]

error message
[image]

nodejs code

```
router.get("/retire/:id", function (req, res, next) {
  const AgentId = req.params.id;
  const sql = `SELECT * FROM agentavia WHERE id= ${AgentId}`;
  db.query(sql, function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.render("retireagent", { title: "Agent List", agentData: data});
  });
});

router.put("/retire/:id", function (req, res, next) {
  const AgentId = req.params.id;
  const sql = `UPDATE agentavia SET agentStatus = 'Retired' WHERE id=?`;
  db.query(sql, [AgentId], function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data.affectedRows + " record(s) updated");
  });
  res.redirect("/admin");
});
```

html code with table and submit button

```
<form id = "retire" action = "/admin/retire/:id" method = "PUT"> 

<div class="agent-detail">     
   
      <table border="1">
            <tr>
              <th>S.N</th>
              <th>Agent Name</th>
              <th>Agent ID</th>
              <th>AgentStatus</th>
            </tr>
          
            <% if(agentData.length!= 0){ let i=1; agentData.forEach(function(data){ %>
            <tr>
              <td><%=i; %></td>
              <td><%=data.agentName %></td>
              <td><%=data.agentID %></td>
              <td><%=data.agentStatus %></td>
            </tr>
            <% i++; }) %> <% } else{ %>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="7">No Data Found</td>
            </tr>
            <% } %>
          </table>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: If I use put, it gives me a parse error - ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':id' at line 1 at Query.Sequence._packetToError (C:\Users\hille\OneDrive\Desktop\WebAssignment\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)

Comment: I found one more error, in your controller, can you tell me which line is `93`

Comment: Are you getting correct `id` in `req.params.id`, can you console.log and confirm

Comment: My line 93 is db.query(sql, [id], function (err, data) {

Comment: Regarding the id part, I can get into the html code with table and submit button correctly and display the correct data. But when it comes to submitting it ask about id.

Comment: because you are concatenating `AgentID` in query and then your also sending `[id]` as params to query. And `id` variable is not defined anywhere, it should be `AgentID` but you dont need to pass it because you have concatenated the ID, so use only one thing. I'll suggest do nt use concat, pass it params in `sql.query` and use '?' in query

Answer (score 0):

change your update controller something like below,

Pass correct id from frontend via form action (which seems difficult to me) or by using `onSubmit` event and call that API

```js
router.put("/retire/:id", function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.params.id); // <----log this
  const AgentId = req.params.id;
  const sql = `UPDATE agentavia SET agentStatus = 'Retired' WHERE id=?}`;
   db.query(sql, [AgentId], function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data.affectedRows + " record(s) updated");
  });
  res.redirect("/admin");
});
```

i might have done syntax error but you should get the idea

Comment: I get this error though.
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':id' at line 1 at Query.Sequence._packetToError (C:\Users\hille\OneDrive\Desktop\WebAssignment\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)

Comment: I have changed my html post to put.
<form id = "retire" action = "/admin/retire/:id" method = "PUT">

Comment: I have updated the code above to show the changes I did.

Comment: @MikeyYoHo, I have added log statement in the answer, try that ......and can you also try hardcoding `id` in the form action. Because `:id` wont get parsed on the front end it'll get parsed in the backend.... I think correct ID is not getting passed

Comment: it seems that it is unable to log id when it come to put.... it reads it as :id

Comment: what does that mean?..... can you hardcode an  `userid` and test

Comment: which ORM or DB connector are you using?

Comment: I use mysql the one one for phpmyadmin one. I use xampp to connect to module

Comment: that's what i said, you are sending string as `:id` from the frontend, it should be a variable but you have multple users getting loaded in table using loop that wont be possible, You'll have to use `onSubmit` event function.

Comment: Oh I need to make another javascript for that onSubmit function? Sorry, I am new to this.

Comment: Yes, but i'm thinking how are you editing the data in table because I'm not sure how will you able get id in your function, Is multiple rows edit possible

Comment: is it an open source project on git? if yes then can you add url here in comment and delete it after if you want...or you can ping me on twitter

Comment: Well, I am able to edit the agent name, id and status in edit mode in that row based on S/N but when it comes to changing a single row status using retire button to change it to retire immediately, I cannot. If is for multiple row, it cannot really edit. It is not on git though. Is there a way I can send through email?

Comment: If you add button in every row to edit `agentStatus` then it would be easier to pass `userID` to the button on which you'll have an `onClick` handler which would call your API

Comment: okay, I will try then update again. Because I was initially asking a few days ago to others in stack overflow about editing two tables by pressing the retire button but I guess it is impossible because no one reply.